# Extend people search, custom result source

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-search

I've made a a custom result source based on "Local SharePoint Results", where I use this "Query Transform"

```
{?(({searchTerms}) ContentClass=urn:content-class:SPSPeople)} 
{?OR (({searchTerms}) spcontenttype:contact)}
```

My search results work, I get both spspeople and contacts.
What I cant figure out is why the spspeople object is presented in the search result as a website. While debugging I noticed that it's indeed a spspeople content class returned.

I want it presented as a "normal" people object with picture and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.I made a copy of the control_searchresults displaytemplate. And included this code in a function(to use title as prefferedname, and prefferedname is used in People item display):

```
 var peopleTable = ctx.ListData.ResultTables.filter(function( table ) {
      return table.TableType == "RelevantResults";
    });


    if( $isEmptyArray(peopleTable) ) return;

    if(!$isEmptyArray(peopleTable)) {

    for (var i=0, item; item = peopleTable[0].ResultRows[i]; i++) {
          item.PreferredName = item.Title;
    }
```

2. In the People search web part chose to use it as a display template.

3.In the webpart: "Use a single template to display items" and chose "People item".